# How good is jBPM for User Tasks workflows?

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

I am evaluating jBPMv5.1 for my next Java Project and was wondering how good and performance intensive is it for User Task Workflows where the task may require user inputs and the user may act upon the task in more than a day. I will also be using Drools for Rule management. I also wish to persist all data and there should be no loss of data due to unexpected failure. I require a framework where I can easily and dynamically plugin new workflows without an added development cost.

Is jBPMv5.1 a good framework for this? I have tried a couple of jBPM examples and read a lot of blogs but am still a little apprehensive about using it lest i run into problems later. Any suggestions or any other framework where I can achieve the same or should I design from scratch keeping my end product in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Abhishek Whatever is your requirement, everything is available in jbpm ,it is very good BPM but as compared to Activity it is bit complex and not so fruitful.

So if you are yet to decide which bpm I would suggest you to go for Activity because integration of anything with Activity say LDAP or Spring is preety easier as compared to JBPM.

Also you can easily learn Activity because of good userguide and documentation provided by community, but in case of JBPM userguide as well as documentation neither are so helpful.
Also Developer guide book is also not up to the mark.

Well ball is in your court ,you have to take decision.

All the Best.

Comment: Thanks @dhaval. I found Activiti better for my use case as it provides integration with Spring easily and it was very easy to configure and use.

Answer (score 3):

@Abhishek
jbpm does precisely what you are asking.
jbpm manages workflows, and that obviously involve human tasks (user tasks as you say it).

typical workflows runs for days even months.

So to answer your question simply, yes jbpm is pretty good with user tasks. Also since you have not decided on the BPM engine yet; you may like to take a look at Activiti BPM http://activiti.org as well.

Answer (score 3):

@abhishek

Congrats to u.
i have found one another link on it

http://www.mastertheboss.com/activiti-bpmn/jbpm-vs-activiti-which-to-choose

Also this is for all who are looking for which bpm to use.